# Can't automatically archive Xcode 8 project through command line

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm trying to archive an Xcode project using `xcodebuild archive` (Xcode 8.2.1) (command line) and a .xcconfig file with the following content:

```
CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = iPhone Developer
DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = [Team name here, removed]
SWIFT_VERSION = 2.3
```

This is the output I am getting

> === BUILD TARGET Unity-iPhone OF PROJECT Unity-iPhone WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===
>
> Check dependencies No profiles for '[bundle id here, removed]' were
>   found:  Xcode couldn't find a provisioning profile matching
>   '[bundle id here, removed]'. Code signing is required for product type
>   'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.2'
>
> ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed:
>           Check dependencies (1 failure)

Comment: Am I right in thinking that I need both a developer certificate, a developer provisioning profile AND the distribution certificate and distribution provisioning profile when archiving through xcodebuild?

Answer (score 1):

You will need a developer certificate, a developer provisioning profile and the distribution certificate and distribution provisioning profile when archiving through xcodebuild, but that still may not be the cause of the check dependency error.